# Occasional ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I developed an ajax based message system with jQuery 3.5.1 and PHP. The users can send messages and 98% of the time the system is working fine.

My problem is that **sometimes** I'm getting an AJAX error: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. My server logs don't shows anything abnormal.
Until now the error has only appeard on Opera/Chrome in Windows in several computers.

My javascript looks like that:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/ajax.send-message.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: sendData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function(res) {
        refreshMessages();
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log('Error: '+textStatus);
    });
```

It seems that something is blocking the connection with my ajax.send-message.php. Perhaps the browser is blocking it because it thinks it's a CORS, but all my scripts are on the same server?

I'm running out of ideas how to solve this issue and I don't understand why this error occurs only some times and not always or never.

Comment: it might not be related to the ajax request at all, it might just be a problem with your PC, or perhaps with your server, especially since it happens **sometimes** and not *all the time*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is in most cases a network problem, it can be happen that a packet is lost during transmission. But it sounds not like a ajax problem.